# typedef in C++ code confusion

Tags: c++, typedef

I came across some code with various typedefs as follows:

```
class GAGenome : public GAID {
public: GADefineIdentity("GAGenome", GAID::Genome);

public:
  typedef float (*Evaluator)(GAGenome &);
  typedef void  (*Initializer)(GAGenome &);
  typedef int   (*Mutator)(GAGenome &, float);
  typedef float (*Comparator)(const GAGenome&, const GAGenome&);
  typedef int   (*SexualCrossover)(const GAGenome&, const GAGenome&, 
               GAGenome*, GAGenome*);
  typedef int   (*AsexualCrossover)(const GAGenome&, GAGenome*);
//some other code
```

I don't understand the 'typedef' usage here, so can anyone teach me what does it mean? It looks a little bit complex here.

Comment: The first problem you have is that this code is written in C++, not C (as the question was originally tagged).  The colons and the `public` keywords alone indicate that; the omnipresent `&` for references is also indicative.

Comment: I'm glad you're only asking about the `typedef`s; the bit that has me puzzled is the meaning of the `GADefineIdentity("GAGenome", GAID::Genome);` line.  If it is a macro (perish the thought), then maybe it makes sense; but as code in a class definition ... I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are defining types that can be used as pointers to functions.

`typedef float (*Evaluator)(GAGenome &);`

This defines the `Evaluator` type as a pointer to a function that takes a reference to `GAGenome` as its single parameter, and returns a `float`.

You could use it like this:

```
float my_Evaluator_Function(GAGenome& g)
{
    // code
    return val;
}

GAGenome::Evaluator pfnEval = my_Evaluator_Function;
float val = pfnEval(myGenome);
```

Answer (score 1):

All six `typedef` declarations specify pointers to functions of various sorts.

The first says that a variable of type `GAGenome::Evaluator` is a pointer to a function that takes a (non-constant) `GAGenome` reference and returns a `float` value.  That is, given:

```
GAGenome x = ...suitable initializer...;
GAGenome::Evaluator e = ...suitable function name...;

float f = e(x);  // Call the function whose pointer is stored in e
```

The other function pointer types are similar, each with their own slightly different meaning due to the different return type or sets of parameters.